# How to get image from json response and display in collection view ios

Tags: ios, arrays, json

I am new to iOS and I am getting an image url from json.. Now I want to display it on collection view. I am doing the below code. But not able to display image in collection view .Anybody Can help me out for this?`enter code here`

// Collection View Code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return imageArray.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0, 50, 80)];
        myImageView.tag = 101;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myImageView];
    }


    NSString *myImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *ImageString = [myImage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"" withString:@"%20"];

    NSLog(@"Image String %@",ImageString);

    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ImageString];

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

    UIImageView *img = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
    img.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor ];

    cell.backgroundView = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    return cell;

}
```

// Json Service

```
NSDictionary *get = @{@"uid":[uidSave valueForKey:@"uid"],@"pro":proNumber};
        NSLog(@"Dictionary Data which is to be get %@",get);

        NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:get options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        NSString *jsonInputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *post = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"r=%@",jsonInputString];

        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",displayCaseUrl]];

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:120.0];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSError *error;
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSData *responseData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        if (responseData != nil)
        {
            jsonDict = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            NSLog(@"Values =======%@",jsonDict);

            NSMutableDictionary *imageDict = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"images"];
            NSLog(@"Image Dictionary :- %@",imageDict);
            imageArray = [imageDict valueForKey:@"image_url"];
            NSLog(@"MY Array Image :- %@",imageArray);
```

// Json Respone from where image is to be get

```
Image Dictionary :- (
        {
        "image_url" = "http://zapponomics.net/claimservice/parcelimage/1486154806image0.jpg";
        "img_for" = "Front view of parcel";
        "pro_number" = orange;
    }
)
2015-08-26 10:09:05.806 ClaimCloud[1997:87342] MY Array String :- (
    "http://zapponomics.net/claimservice/parcelimage/1486154806image0.jpg"
)
```

//////// USIng Like this but does not work

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0, 50, 80)];
    myImageView.tag = 101;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:myImageView];
    NSString *myImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [self loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[myImage stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] callback:^(UIImage *image) {
        myImageView.image = image;
    }];
    return cell;
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0,200);

}
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(100,80);

}
- (void) loadImageFromURL: (NSURL*) url callback:(void (^)(UIImage *image))callback {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            callback(image);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very good library named [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) which will help you to load the image from a URL.As in the above answer of @poojathorat you are converting the image to data, if the images are of larger size, than you will get the memory problem, but this library will manage the memory also.So in my opinion use this library.

Just drag the SDWebImage folder in your project and import

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

then to load the image from URL use this  method

```
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

it will also manage the cache of images.

And if you don't want to include the library then use this function

```
- (void) loadImageFromURL: (NSURL*) url callback:(void (^)(UIImage *image))callback {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            callback(image);
        });
    });
}
```

And use this function like this

```
[self loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:["yourURL" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] callback:^(UIImage *image) {
    yourImageView.image = image;
}]
```

Comment: CAn u tell me without adding any liibrary ?/?

Comment: What is the problem in adding the Library.It will also load image asynchronously.

Comment: I dont wanna include any library.. can u tell me without adding lib

Comment: I have edited answer in case if you are getting any space in your URL.

Comment: It wont be able to display an image in collection view

Comment: It is working in my project, i have just checked it.

Comment: I have checked your code, in cellForItemAtIndexPath you are not going into the if conditon.Manage that properly, also checked the code is working in your code.Images are loading if i have removed the if condition.

Comment: Edited your question, check.

Comment: Thanku Rajatp Ur code will be very helpful for me and it works

Comment: This is another question, ask it on another question.

Answer (score 0):

No need of replacing space by %20.Directly apply by follwing way.

```
NSString *myImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myImage];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
cell. myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:img];
```

Comment: @##poojathorat  It shows error on line UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data cache:NO]; 
and the error is no visible interface for ui image cache

Comment: Now property of imageview is not found .. shows error on last line cell. myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:img];

Comment: UIImageView *myImageView declare this above  if(!cell) condition

Comment: You have declared it in if condition so this property is not getting